# Multiplying columns with a constant value in pandas. Type Error

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe :

```
Event          Modelled flow (cfs)   Observed Flow (cfs)
Event 01           0.8610723               2.105263
Event 01           0.8596087               2.383901
Event 01           0.8749821               2.092879
Event 01           0.9045072               2.119195
Event 01           0.9267832               2.156347
Event 01           0.9156083               1.883901
```

I want to add 2 new column by multiplying existing columns by a value 300 as shown below:

```
df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = df['Modelled Flow (cfs)']*300.00
df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = df['Observed Flow (cfs)']*300.00
```

If i use the above code, i'm getting the below error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How can i rectify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First try cast to `float`:

```
df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = df['Modelled flow (cfs)'].astype(float)*300.00
df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = df['Observed Flow (cfs)'].astype(float)*300.00
print (df)
      Event  Modelled flow (cfs)  Observed Flow (cfs)  Modelled Volume(f3)  \
0  Event 01             0.861072             2.105263            258.32169   
1  Event 01             0.859609             2.383901            257.88261   
2  Event 01             0.874982             2.092879            262.49463   
3  Event 01             0.904507             2.119195            271.35216   
4  Event 01             0.926783             2.156347            278.03496   
5  Event 01             0.915608             1.883901            274.68249   

   Observed Volume(f3)  
0             631.5789  
1             715.1703  
2             627.8637  
3             635.7585  
4             646.9041  
5             565.1703
```

If first solution failed, convert columns [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with parameter `errors='coerce'` for replace problematic values to `NaN`:

```
df['Modelled Volume(f3)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Modelled flow (cfs)'], errors='coerce')*300.00
df['Observed Volume(f3)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Observed Flow (cfs)'], errors='coerce')*300.00
print (df)
      Event  Modelled flow (cfs)  Observed Flow (cfs)  Modelled Volume(f3)  \
0  Event 01             0.861072             2.105263            258.32169   
1  Event 01             0.859609             2.383901            257.88261   
2  Event 01             0.874982             2.092879            262.49463   
3  Event 01             0.904507             2.119195            271.35216   
4  Event 01             0.926783             2.156347            278.03496   
5  Event 01             0.915608             1.883901            274.68249   

   Observed Volume(f3)  
0             631.5789  
1             715.1703  
2             627.8637  
3             635.7585  
4             646.9041  
5             565.1703
```

Comment: Thank you. Further if i'm trying to get percentage change for 2 columns, i'm getting this error: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str', though they are columns containing float values. What's the problem?

Comment: It is same as solve this solution - columns are string, not numeric. so try cast to `float` `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(float)` and if failed, `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col'], errors='coerce')`